# MySql query for relation two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have three different tables (**country, product, biz**) in my database and they are represented as the following

```
**Country Table**
id --- countryName

**Product Table**
id --- productName --- countryID(FK)

**Biz Table**
id --- bizName --- countryID(FK) ---- productID(FK)
```

In my biz table, the countryID and productID columns have Foreign Key on country and product table respectively

What will my query look like if I want to insert business name into biz table? Will I have to get the id from the product table?

Comment: If `biz` is always linked to `product` then yes.

Comment: If the `CountryID` in `Biz` is _always_ going to be the same as the `CountryID` in the associated `Product` then `Biz.ProductID` becomes redundant and there's no need to keep it imho

Comment: This schema doesn't make much sense. Does each Business only sell one product to one country?

Comment: @Barmar so there are many business values a country can have and for now each country has just one product value but there could many products tied to a country

Comment: My question is the other way around: Can a business have multiple product or multiple countries? You should have separate tables: a `Business` table with one row for each business, and `BusinessProductCountry` table that relates the businesses to the products and countries.

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a normal insert like:

INSERT INTO BizTable (id,bizName,countryID,productID) VALUES(1,'business',1,1)

Having countryID(FK) and productID(FK) as foreign keys only means that the id you insert need to exist in the other tables otherwise SQL will give an error and not allow the insert